# Finding the Volume of a Torus by rotating a circle with equation $x^2 + (y-R)^2 = r^2$ a different way

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

I was trying to find the Volume of a Torus and after sketching it out in Desmos, I thought I found a solution but it doesn't work (or at least when I evaluated it it didn't work).

$V = 2π\int_{-r}^r(\sqrt{r^2-x^2}+R)^2-R^2\ dx$

My reasoning was that I would take the integral of the top half of the circle subtracted by the integral of the line cutting the circle in half and then multiply the whole thing by two to get the total volume. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What makes you think the inner part of the torus has the same volume as the outer parr?

Comment: Because $x^2+(y-R)^2 = r^2$ is the formula for a circle so if I integrate half of the circle and multiply by 2 I should get the whole volume, right? I could be mistaken as I obviously cannot solve the problem.

Comment: No they're different distances away from the $x$ axis. Also that didn't answer my question and why you're reasoning failed. The $2$D interpretation doesn't always line up with the $3$D shape.

Comment: Ok, I think I get what you are saying. From a 3D perspective, I definitely see that the outer half and the inner half are different sizes. I was just thinking that volume = integral of area so I went with that. Thanks for the explanation.